# Regex before or after

Tags: php, regex

I would to use regex to match the string `tofind`

I have two possibilities the 1st

```
before tofind
```

Te second is

```
tofind after
```

How to match the word tofind in the two examples with one regex line?

I used

```
before (tofind) | (tofind) after
```

It gave them on the match 1 and the match 2

I would have the result always in array match 1

I'm using php :

```
if (preg_match("/before (tofind) | (tofind) after/", $content, $result))
        return trim($result[1]);
```

thank you

Comment: Why do you need it to work like that? Why not `return $result[1] ? trim($result[$1]) : trim($result[2])`?

Comment: Hello thank you Barmar could you please tell me if it works if I have also tree or four | (or) ?

Comment: You would need nested conditional expressions, or you could use a loop to find and return the first one that matches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [branch reset](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) feature:

```
(?|before (tofind)|(tofind) after)
```

now the two capture groups have the same number.

Note: you can do the same with a named capture (and no need to repeat the name of the capture group):

```
(?|before (?<mycap>tofind)|(tofind) after)
```

or using the `(?J)` modifier that allows duplicate names (must be placed at the begining before the named groups, it is not available as a global modifier you can put after the end delimiter):

```
(?J)(?:before (?<mycap>tofind)|(?<mycap>tofind) after)
```

Comment: Very nice Casimir, little known features. Do you think this would be fine too: `(?|before (tofind)|((?1)) after)`

Comment: @Jonny5: Why not, if the subpattern is long (and is the same).

Answer (score 5):

To add another option to Casimir's lovely answer, here's a solution that works in regex flavors that don't have `(?|` syntax. It relies on a simple alternation with a lookbehind and a lookahead. Since the goal is the have the token in Group 1, the alternation is wrapped in capturing parentheses.

```
((?<=before )tofind|tofind(?= after))
```